# Word for "term for inhabitant of"

Tags: single-word-requests

I am looking for a word which means "term for inhabitant of". An example sentence would be:

> The _________ of London is Londoner.

This is **not** a duplicate of the marked question as it asks what is a "term for inhabitant of", the answer being demonym - this is completely different to the supposedly duplicate question and I would appreciate these requests being retracted.

Comment: Are you looking for "demonym?" "Inhabitant of" doesn't fit in the blank, so your question is a bit awkward.

Comment: @jejorda2 Yes I was looking for this; I realise now it was phrased awkwardy and did not clarify I was looking for a word to describe the term not the person. Thank you to all the answers, my mistake was in the wording.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Denizen](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/denizen?s=t)**:

> - an inhabitant; resident.

(dictionary.reference.com)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=denizen%20of%20London&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdenizen%20of%20London%3B%2Cc0): *denizen of London*

Answer (score 1):

Native will work well for that purpose, I think.
http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/native

Comment: Naydivs: local types born and reared in da Bronz. (From "Noo Yawk Tawk ").

Answer (score 0):

***citizen***

> :  an inhabitant of a city or town; especially :  one entitled to the
>   rights and privileges of a freeman [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/citizen)

[**Ngram**](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=citizen+of+London%2Cinhabitant+of+London&year_start=1900&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ccitizen%20of%20London%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cinhabitant%20of%20London%3B%2Cc0)